# Login to Facebook through a c# application and then open up the web browser

Tags: c#, .net, facebook

I have an c# application that authenticates users, and I would like to be able to login to Facebook through my application. When I've authenticated my user, I'd like the default web browser to open and show the facebook.com page. Just to be clear: I *do not* want to post any data to the wall, no uploaded pictures or messaging from my application, just the login part.

**So: I want to somehow login to Facebook through a C# application, but then continue the session through the user's web browser.**

The point is that the end user don't have to see any login-page from Facebook, but instead authenticates through my application.

Any ideas? Anything is appreciated.

Comment: I recently did successfully submit an application that connects to Dropbox. It uses OAuth. I assume Facebook does the same. So basically you need an OAuth library and then use it in your C# code. From my understanding this _always_ requires to show a Facebook login page to the end user.

Comment: @Uwe: But is there any way to *not* show a login page from Facebook?

Comment: I doubt. Maybe screen scraping?

Comment: Once you are logged in you may do variety of actions via Facebook Graph API or some wrapper - but by design the login itself have to be done via "Facebook" login page. So maybe screen scraping could be your solution as mentioned by Uwe Keim.